# Set maximum time for download with wget recursive

Tags: bash, shell, web-crawler, wget, mirroring

I am crawling multiple webpages with wget. However with some of then it would keep downloading files forever, so I run it from a bash script which kills it 10 minutes after start.

However wget does link conversion at last (`--convert-links`) and if I kill it the files would have the original links and it would be not suitable for local viewing.

Is there a way to time-limit wget with `--mirror` option?

Timeout would kill wget, which is what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: See: `man wget | grep timeout`

Comment: These timeout applies on each request, I want a maximum time for the global process aka stop downloading new files after some time has passed

Comment: @kvantour Timeout would kill wget, which is what i'm trying to avoid. Please read the question.